# Ruby random array call for each pass in a loop?

Tags: ruby, variables, loops

How do I have Ruby re-process the rand method on my "atk" variable for each instance? Right now, the program takes a random atk number on the first pass and then uses it for the rest of the program. Any advice is very welcome!

```
playerhp = 100
enemyhp = 100
monster = ["Johnny Bravo", "Father Christmas", "Boobzilla", "Lady Gaga", "Derpy-chan"]
m = monster[rand(monster.length)]
melee = [7, 10, 12, 14, 22]
atk = melee[rand(melee.length)]

puts "Your are approached by a horrid looking " + m + "!"
sleep(1)
puts "The " + m + " looks you coldy in the eye and then charges for an attack!"
sleep(1)

while playerhp > 0 do
    puts "The " + m + " has " + enemyhp.to_s + " remaining. What will you do? (type 'attack' or 'defend')"
    action = gets.chomp
        if action == "attack" then
            thisatk = atk.to_i
            enemyhp = enemyhp - thisatk
            puts "You hit the " + m + " for " + thisatk.to_s + " damage!"
        end
        if action == "defend" then
            puts "You crouch in a defensive position!"
        end

    if enemyhp < 1 then
        puts "You completely destroyed that " + m + "! Victory!"
        break   
    end
end
```

I'm sure this is the worst looking Ruby code you've ever seen, but please bear in mind that **it's my first program with Ruby (just started today)**. I do this on the first day I spend learning any language.

I fail at reading books... the only way I can learn a language is to make a combat game with it. I find it to be the best way to get me in an environment I recognize and learn a lot at the same time.

Comment: You probably want your monsters to look you **coldly** in the eye.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Oh god... I'm an idiot. I processed the randomization outside the loop @_@.

Sorry for the embarrassment folks. For anyone interested, if you're as stupid as I am:

Removed the "atk" variable

Moved the melee[rand(melee.length)]
    method INTO the loop.

New process looks like this:

```
if action == "attack" then
        thisatk = melee[rand(melee.length)]
        enemyhp = enemyhp - thisatk
        puts "You hit the " + m + " for " + thisatk.to_s + " damage!"
    end
```

If anyone has some additional commentary for how to better code that particular action, I'm all ears!!

Comment: @tokland: Don't use `Array#choice`, it was renamed to `Array#sample` in 1.9.2.

Comment: @Marc, well, I use the one I have :-) many distros still ship Ruby 1.8.7 by default.

Comment: Array#sample is much cleaner. Thanks for the tip guys!